# PHP login verification not working OR logout not working

Tags: php, authentication

I am able to login to my page but when I click logout and type the URL in the address bar, it still allows me to enter. This leads me to believe that it is not properly verifying my credentials therefor allowing me to enter regardless. It's been a while since I used PHP so I am not completely up-to-date so any help would be appreciated.

Start of page that requires login in order to access:

```
<?php session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['myusername'] !== 'myusername'){
 header("location:main_login.php");
 }
 ?>
```

My checklogin.php:

```
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "blogedit.php"
session_start();
 $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
 $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
 header("location:/blogedit.php");
 } else {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Username and password entered do not match. Please try     again.');
window.location.href='/main_login.php';
</SCRIPT>");
}
```

My logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();  
session_destroy();
header("Location: /journal.php");
?>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside checklogin.php? If not, add it.

Comment: This `$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;` is highly discouraged. Ever heard of session hijacking? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Comment: ^ Especially considering there appears to be no use for the password in session.

Comment: What Exactly you want to do in this Statement:

if(!$_SESSION['myusername']= 'myusername'){

It looks wrong to me.
I think it need to be:

if($_SESSION['myusername']== 'myusername'){

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is not, does it matter where I add it?

Comment: It must be above `$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;` in checklogin.php very important. Must be inside all files using sessions.

Comment: @user3758073 Once that is done see Ashish's comment or my answer, you're actually authenticating everyone with the single `=` in your if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$_SESSION['myusername']= 'myusername') {
   # this will never be hit
}
```

You need to use a comparison operator.  `=` is not a comparison operator.  `=` will attempt to set the left side equivalent to the right side.  In this case (with a string) this will always succeed.  You should use `!==`:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) or $_SESSION['myusername'] !== 'myusername') {
   # user not authenticated
}
```

As Fred stated, with the `!` in front of `$_SESSION['myusername']` you are checking if `$_SESSION['myusername']` is not empty (0, false, null) but you are setting it equivalent to 'myusername' in the same passing.  That is why the contents of the if statement will never be hit.

You also must include `session_start();` inside checklogin.php since it is required to be inside all pages using sessions.

Comment: Actually, I think OP is trying to check if it is not set. Isn't using right syntax for it.

Comment: @Devon So I added these changes. Now, I am not able to access the page at all, even with the correct login information or when I visit the URL. My updated code is above.

Comment: Could also do `if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){...}` or `if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION['myusername'] !='myusername')){...}`

Comment: @Fred-ii-     `if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){...}`      is what did the trick, thanks a bunch. Is it beneficial if you post this as the answer and I accept it?

Comment: @user3758073 It's ok. Let Devon include it in the answer. I'm just glad I was able to help, *cheers* - Once he does, you can accept it.

Comment: @Devon Can you do the honors? Since there's already an answer. I rather that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks.  I have updated my answer to include the isset.